# Set Environment Variables in Rails' Webrick Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

we're using some Company-wide Auth-Module ( entrust getaccess) which basically leaves some environment variables after authentication (gid, username, etc...).

To fake this auth for testing purposes I'd set the following env varibales in apache:

```
        SetEnv "AUTH_TYPE" "Entrust-GetAccess"
        SetEnv "HTTP_SCTCGID" "johndoe"
```

Is this somehow possible with the WebRICK Server, too?

best regards,
Björn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your development.rb file:

```
ENV['AUTH_TYPE'] = "Entrust-GetAccess"
ENV['HTTP_SCTCGID'] = "johndoe"
```

If you need this on other environments, put it on the respective staging.rb or production.rb, or just on application.rb to set them on all environments.